# Javascript using promises to get back results of php script and display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, promise

I am still new to javascript and trying to create a promise function to run a php script and use the return data to do something. I've done this  using ajax and it works. I was wondering if the promise does the same thing as my ajax function. Here are my ajax/promise functions:

using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"../php/getuserdata.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text", 
    success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $("#user-data-table tbody").append(result);
    }
});
```

using promises:

```
function getUserData(){
    var url = "../php/getuserdata.php";
    fetch(url).then(function(response) {
        return response.text()
    }).then(function(text) {
        console.log(text);
        $("#user-data-table tbody").append(text);
    });
}
```

Can I use the promise like this? Also, are promises only using GET by default?

Comment: You can use a Promise for whatever you like. It's simply a wrapper for typically async actions. One word of warning, if using `then`, you may want to chain a `catch` block too in order to [prevent the Promise swallowing your errors](http://jamesknelson.com/are-es6-promises-swallowing-your-errors/). This caught me out recently.

Comment: @fubar Thanks! When I use fetch does it do a GET?

Comment: `fetch` makes a `GET` request by default. You can read more about the [config options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) on the MDN website.

Comment: @fubar Thanks again. So will the above two functions do the same thing essentially?

Comment: Yep. Although `$.ajax` will handle `4xx` and `5xx` error responses. With `fetch` you need to do that yourself. This is all covered in the docs though.